# Cordova-plugin-qrscanner: Scanning barcode when not in the center of the preview

Tags: ionic3, cordova-plugins

I would like to move scanning area from the center of the screen, to be able to scann barcode within preview but above middle of the screen, does anyone know where how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

This is still as an open [issue](https://github.com/bitpay/cordova-plugin-qrscanner/issues/197) in the project.

I was facing the same issue. The easiest workaround I found (**for Android**) was to tweak the [setupCamera()](https://github.com/bitpay/cordova-plugin-qrscanner/blob/master/src/android/QRScanner.java#L449) function in `QRScanner.java`.

Because the *decode happens* from approximately the *mid-one-third of the screen*, the trick is to **relatively shift this center region** by changing the `height value` of the `cameraPreviewParams` in the function.

If you look at [my implementation](https://github.com/james11a/cordova-plugin-qrscanner/blob/master/src/android/QRScanner.java#L450), I am using the `DisplayMetrics` to find the height of the screen and then **halving it** to display the camera preview only in the top half of the screen. This effectively also shifts the decode area further up the screen. Use this height value in `cameraPreviewParams`.

Though this may not be ideal solution, it was easiest workaround I found (though I had to wreck my head many days as I do not know Java and the Android API) and it works flawlessly for me.

**Note:** Yes, you will need to create your own fork of this project and use it in your application.